# Is there a way to use regex with awk to execute a command only when the pattern is matched?

Tags: regex, linux, awk, wget

I'm trying to write a bash script that gets user input, checks a .txt for the line that contains that input then plugs that into a wget statement to commence a download.

In testing the functionality awk seems to print out every line, not just pattern matched lines.

```
chosen=DSC01985
awk -v c="$chosen" 'BEGIN {FS="/"; /c/}
{print  $8, "found", c}
END{print " done"}' ./imgLink.txt
```

The above should take from imgLink.txt, search for the pattern and return that the pattern is found. Instead it prints the the 8th field of every line in the file.

I have tried moving /c/ out of the begin statement but to no avail.

what's going on here?

Example input:

https://xxxx/xxxx/xxxx/xxxx/xxx/DSC01533.jpg

https://xxxx/xxxx/xxxx/xxxx/xxx/DSC01536.jpg

https://xxxx/xxxx/xxxx/xxxx/xxx/DSC01543.jpg

https://xxxx/xxxx/xxxx/xxxx/xxx/DSC01558.jpg

https://xxxx/xxxx/xxxx/xxxx/xxx/DSC01565.jpg
etc.

Example output:

...

DSC02028.jpg found DSC01985

DSC02030.jpg found DSC01985

DSC02032.jpg found DSC01985

DSC02038.jpg found DSC01985

DSC02042.jpg found DSC01985
etc.

Comment: Welcome to SO and special thanks for showing your efforts in your question. Please post sample of input and expected sample output too in your question for better understanding, kindly do edit your question and let us know then.

Comment: question kindly edited, happy to oblige if you need any further information

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were close in your attempt, you can't search an `awk` variable like `/var/` you need different method for this. Could you please try following.Considering that your string which you want to look will come in URL value(s) which you have currently `xxx`ed in your post.

```
awk -v c="$chosen" -F'/' '$0 ~ c{print $NF " found " c}' Input_file
```

Not sure why you have written `done` in your END block, you could add it here if you need it. Also `$NF` means last field of current line you could print it as per your need too.

Comment: Alright, awesome. so this worked perfectly BUT could I be so bold as to ask a few questions to further my understanding:

1) -F 'F'  vs 'Begin {FS="/"}      

2)$NF vs $8            

3) /[pattern]/ vs ~           

4) it seems that the key thing is that the regex is on the same line as the expression? Is this just and awk-ism?

Comment: @plebert, setting field separator either by `-F` or by `FS="` method is more or less same you could use anyone of them. For searching thing if you mention anything inside `/..../` then it will be considered as a regexp and will look for that match(not for its value's match) hence it has to be used like this way, cheers and happy learning on this great forum SO.